# how to use Firebase Cloud Functions with promises and forEach?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to do TWO things here.
1)Send a notification to all employees. 2)Copy a Specific ref to the
   Employees id ref. if no Special ref exists i will copy General ref.
The program runs without errors. Infact its perfect. But sometimes i get a Timed out error with the Notifications code part.

> Error: fcm.googleapis.com network timeout. Please try again.

The code that copys one reference to another, always works, never ever received an error there.
I feel the error is due to not correctly handling promises with forEach. Could you help me get this code to excecute flawlessly, with correctly placed Promises?

```
exports.myFunc = functions.https.onRequest( (request, response) => {

admin.database().ref('/Employees').once('value').then(function(snap) {
    snap.forEach(function (snapshot) {
        var obj = snapshot.val();

        if(obj.department){//only go ahead if dept is present
            console.log(' : ' + obj.department);
            var id, tkid, dept;
            id = obj.empId; tkid = obj.tokenId; dept = obj.department;

            var welcomeStr="hello! Welcom to our Department";

            //================================================================notifications
            var payload = {
                data: {
                  greeting: welcomeStr,
                  to_who: id
                }
              };
                    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tkid,payload)
                    .then(function(response){
                        console.log("Successfully sent message: ", response);
                    })
                    .catch(function(error){
                            console.log("Error sending message: ", error);
                    })
            //===================================================Ref copying

            var destinationRef = admin.database().ref('/Employees/' + id);//final destination
            var option2Ref = admin.database().ref('/Company/General');//when special doesnt exist
            var option1Ref = admin.database().ref('/Company/Special');//if special exists

            option1.once('value', function(snapshot1){
                if (snapshot1.exists()){//copy from straing from option11 to Employees/id
                    option1.once('value', function(snap)  {
                        destinationRef.set( snap.val(), function(error) {
                            if( error && typeof(console) !== 'undefined' && console.error ) {  console.error(error); }

                            console.log('DONE ....  ' + id);
                        });
                    });
                }

                else{//we need to copy from option2 to Employees/id
                    option2Ref.once('value', function(snap)  {
                        newRef.set( snap.val(), function(error) {
                            if( error && typeof(console) !== 'undefined' && console.error ) {  console.error(error); }

                            console.log('DONE .... ' + id);
                        });
                    });
                }

            });
        }
        else{
            console.log('No Department: ' + obj.dept);
            return;
        }
    });

 });


response.send("WOKAY!");
});
```

Comment: i believe you've correctly identified that the `forEach` loop is the core of your problem — most likely, each iteration of the loop is launching another promise chain which is not returned — i think you're experiencing dropped promises..

Comment: Your actually right... Sometimes the log print 2-3times the same result.

Answer (score 2):

here i've rewritten your code in hopes to clean up the complicated promise chains

dropped promises are one of the most common and difficult problems to debug, i've seen my fair share

important changes to your code:

1. **modern `async` syntax**

   - so that the promises are cleaner to organize
2. **use `Promise.all` instead of `forEach`**

   - this way every promise is awaited without being forgotten
   - (hopefully) all of the promises are returned properly
   - all snapshot operations are run concurrently, and the onRequest handler should wait until they're all finished before terminating
3. **using promises for `once` and `set` instead of callbacks**

   - i'm not really sure what libraries these are
   - it looks like they accept promise-based usage
   - so i eliminated callback usage in favor of promises
4. **please review the TODO mark**

   - not really sure what's intended for that else block, so be sure to patch that up

---

```
async function handleSnapshot(snapshot) {
  const {empId, tokenId, department} = snapshot.val()

  // only go ahead if dept is present
  if (!department) throw new Error("no department")
  console.log("department:", department)

  //================================================================notifications
  const payload = {
    data: {
      greeting: "Hello! Welcome to our Department",
      to_who: empId
    }
  }
  const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenId, payload)
  console.log("successfully sent message", response)
  //===================================================Ref copying

  const destinationRef = admin.database().ref('/Employees/' + empId) // final destination
  const option2Ref = admin.database().ref('/Company/General') // when special doesnt exist
  const option1Ref = admin.database().ref('/Company/Special') // if special exists

  const snapshot1 = await option1Ref.once("value")

  // copy from string from option1 to Employees/id
  if (snapshot1.exists()) { 
    await destinationRef.set(snapshot1.val())
    console.log("DONE1...", empId)
  }

  // TODO review this block
  // we need to copy from option2 to Employees/id
  else {
    const snapshot2 = await option2Ref.once("value")
    await destinationRef.set(snapshot2.val())
    console.log("DONE2...", empId)
  }
}

exports.myFunc = functions.https.onRequest(async(request, response) => {
  const snapshots = await admin.database().ref('/Employees').once('value')
  await Promise.all(snapshots.map(handleSnapshot))
  response.send("WOKAY!")
})
```

Comment: Im getting an error at "(async(request,response)=>" -  it says- "SyntaxError: Unexpected token (".... I have the latest version of Node. what may i do?

Comment: Is this because async/await doesn't work with firebase cloud functions??

Comment: @ChaseMoskal still getting that same error... Any help??

Comment: @user3833732 — its very possible i've accidentally mispositioned some parenthesis or some other syntax error

Comment: @user3833732 — we're reaching the limit of what we can do for you here on stackoverflow — i strongly suggest you explore the topic of `unit testing` — ultimately, you should be mocking up your database calls so that you can iron out the bugs in your functionality and debug them properly in a testing environment — i strongly suggest you look into the `jest` testing framework

Comment: @ChaseMoskal, I have checked parenthesis, they are all perfect. The problem is the word "async" in-  functions.https.onRequest(async(request, response). On deploying it wont allow me to go ahead. I just need to know, is it allowed to put "async" in  functions.https.onRequest(async(request, response)? for Firebase Cloud Functions? If I have that confirmed may be then I could find my way. But that very first step is failing, so I cant move on.

Comment: i suspect you are using an outdated copy of node

Comment: @ChaseMoskal, I have updated my version of Node to v10. and updated all my dependencies too. everything seems correct except that very same thing. It doesnt allow me to use "async" in "functions.https.onRequest(async(request, response) =>"... Is there any way we could run this without putting async in that line. Because i couldnt find any documentations or examples online where "async" has been put between ".onRequest("... and... "(request,responce)=>"

Comment: That's exactly what I am facing. I am not able to proceed from that very same line even after updating Node. @chasemoskal, is there any other way to make something like this with a foreach loop ?

Comment: we cannot use a foreach, we're not looping, we're actually providing a callback

Comment: if you remove the "async", then you have to convert the "await" usage back to .then's -- i wouldn't ever do that, the real solution is to find the sytax error, and ensure your js environment supports async/await

Comment: Neither do i want to go back to ".thens"--- but its been more than a week, and i have checked every document online and there is not a single resource that shows " functions.https.onRequest(async(request, response) =>"... And I have never use this, so its impossible for me to correct this code! I have updated all my stuff, node/dependencies/firebase tools etc etc...  I once again ask you, "Are you sure we are allowed to put the word "async" in the first line of that http function??

Comment: I was looking through my "node_modules" folder and could only find "async" & "asynckit" but not Asyncawait or Async-await... Which is the correct one for this type of async/wait code?

Comment: @YoApps -- yes, you can pass an async function to `onRequest` -- you must be sure all code termination points end with an http response being sent, however -- async is not common in older docs, but now it is a standard best practice

Comment: @user3833732 -- async/await is a standard javascript language feature -- look it up, and update your node installation

Comment: @ChaseMoskal, thanks, will try. I read somewhere that you will have to use TypeScript to make this work. And just like user3833723 mentioned, I noticed loads of other modules not installed in my node_modules folder, like async, await, asyncawait, async-await, async--await... so which might be the ones I really need?... and do i have to shift to TypeScript?

Comment: @YoApps -- no need to switch to typescript, async/await is just a javascript feature -- also, no modules are required for async/await -- that would be like installing mode_modules for `if` statements

Comment: you must look up and master "async await" coding practices *before* you attempt working in javascript

Comment: async await is a modern feature, so you cant have an ancient node installation -- use node 10, however i think node 8+ supports async await

Comment: @ChaseMoskal you're correct. I read the same thing that you said. But NO luck. I once again reinstalled every thing. But it wont accept "async". Really frustrating. I made another function too with the "async"... But where ever in the code "async" appears it gives a syntax error! Just cant understand... so upsetting. And i like this Async/Await style you showed me so i dont want to go back either to the ".thens". But this just beats me, Any ideas?

Comment: @ChaseMoskal, I tried another example to do with async await, besides your code.. And the outcome was the same. It never allowed me to deploy it to firebase cloud server. Syntax error. EsLint shows no error either. Its very similar to errors people who had an old version of node and tried to run async. But my version is 10!

Comment: @ChaseMoskal- as user3933732 said, I too wasnt able to run another "async" code. I also found this in the GoogleDocs: "The Cloud Functions Node.js execution environment follows the Node "LTS" releases, starting with the v6 LTS release published on 2016-10-18. The current Node.js version running in Cloud Functions is Node v6.11.5."

Comment: So doesnt this mean the Async await solution is of no use to us?

Comment: @user3833732, YoApps — interesting, considering node 8 has been in active 'lts' for a little while now — i recommend: (first) find a way to have the cloud platform run your application under a newer version of node; (second) consider something like a container-based cloud service that lets you control your own node installation, like with docker; (third) alternatively continue using your current cloud provider and use typescript or babel to transpile async code to es5 to run on node 6; (finally) above all, i recommend continuing to code with the async/await pattern under all circumstances

Comment: @ChaseMoskal, I did as you said, Im using the async/await pattern with TypeScript. It runs Async/Await. But I am getting another error: "TypeError: snapshots.map is not a function"... on the line: await Promise.all(snapshots.map(handleSnapshot)). Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

To add one very important step to @ChaseMoskal answer.
For those using TypeScript with Firebase, since firebase server is not running v8+ in NodeJs, theres a great chance you might get this error:

> "TypeError: snapshots.map is not a function"... on the line: await Promise.all(snapshots.map(handleSnapshot)).

Thats cause in your tsconfig.json its possibly **"lib": ["es6"]**. In that case just add this small snippet to the accepted answer, to get the Firebase Datasnapshot into an array that could be used with .map(...)

**Longer Version:**

```
exports.myFunc = functions.https.onRequest(async(request, response) => {
const snapshots = await admin.database().ref('/Employees').once('value')

    var data_snap_arr = [];
        snapshots.forEach(function(child_Snapshot) {
            var stuff = child_Snapshot.val();
            stuff.key = child_Snapshot.key;
            data_snap_arr.push(stuff);

await Promise.all(data_snap_arr.map(handleSnapshot))
response.send("WOKAY!")
})
```

**Shorter Version:**

```
exports.myFunc = functions.https.onRequest(async(request, response) => {
const snapshots = await admin.database().ref('/Employees').once('value')

   let data_snap_arr = Object.keys(snapshots.val() || {}) .map(k => snapshots.val()[k]);

await Promise.all(data_snap_arr.map(handleSnapshot))
response.send("WOKAY!")
})
```

Comment: I had actually given up on this, but will now be able to work with the accepted answer